# is python multiprocessing.Process start() doing the same job as subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, subprocess, multiprocessing

I am a newbie in Python. I recently tried to use Python script to call an console exe which is a process need long time. I will allow the exe being called as many times as the CPU can permit. And when the exe has finish its job. The CPU can be allocated to other new jobs. So I think I may need the multiple process control mechanism.

Before I switch to multiprocessing.Process I can call my exe from subprocess.Popen. It works fine. However, after I switched to multiprocessing.Process. It seems start() can not call my exe (I can tell the difference from CPU performance). Can anyone give a clue on this? FYI, I am using the following code.

previously using subrpocess:

```
cmd = exeFileName + r" " + inputArguments

a = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Now using multipleprocess:

```
b = multiprocessing.Process(target=exeFileName,args=inputArguments)

b.start()
```

As you may noticed, my exe need input arguments to work. So in the subprocess code, I use a string of cmd to capture the whole line. In multiprocessing code, I am not. It already has a target and args built-in.
Thank you for your time!

Comment: Got it work finally. I discard multiprocessing at the end. Instead, I am using subprocess and its own poll() method to tell me whether the exe has terminated or not. Then append them to thread. It seems to work now.

Answer (score 5):

Use `subprocess.Popen` to run other executables in a subprocess.

Use `multiprocessing.Process` to run Python callables (e.g. functions) in a subprocess.

The two are not interchangeable.

Comment: I got it. I have to wrap my one line subprocess.Popen in a python function and then call from multiprocessing and it will work.

Comment: But one problem, it seems the exe is executed before I use multiprocessing.Process start() function. I want to us multiprocessing machanism to control and allocate available CPU for the exe.

Comment: @Mua: I'm not sure multiprocessing.Process is going to do what you desire. In particular, using multiprocessing.Process to fork a subprocess which subsequently calls subprocess.Popen to fork a subsubprocess is not managing resources well -- it's probably just using more resources (2 processes instead of 1). If you can describe in more detail how you want the processes managed, perhaps someone can suggest a way to do it. At this point, I'm not certain multiprocessing is the right tool.

Comment: thank you, unutbu. I have opened another question for that. What I want to do is to use multiprocessing mechanism to control several long running exe. When they finish their job, release the CPU. Or user can choose to abort the exe in the middle of process. Still have no good ideas on that. :(